# PHP GET Passed To Second URL

Tags: php, post, get

So I had a script running for the whitelist / blacklist feature in my email campaign. I would set the URL http://www.mywebsite1.com/whitelist.php?email= for instance and use a GET to grab whatever email my sending software had populated in. When the user clicked the link it would take the email out of the link and execute a SQL command to add it to a database. Now that database has moved but there's over 1 million emails in circulation with the old white and blacklist links still in them. So I figured a simple PHP script to grab the email like before but this time add it to the end of the new domain/script location and execute the link to trigger the same process on the new database.

I want someone to navigate to say http://www.mywebsite1.com/whitelist.php?email=test@email.com

and have it execute a script to append "test@email.com" to the end of the new url and then execute it. So it would be http://www.mywebsite2.com/whitelist.php?email=test@email.com.

I wrote what I thought was a simple script for this but think I dropped the ball somewhere..

```
<?php 
$email = $_GET['email'];
if($email != ''){  
$url = 'http://www.mywebsite2.com/whitelist.php?email='$email; 

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/6.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.7) Gecko/20050414 Firefox/1.0.3");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    $result = curl_exec ($ch); 
    curl_close ($ch);
    }
?>
```

So the user should go to mywebsite1.com and this script is supposed to capture their email and add it to the end of mywebsite2.com and then trigger the link to load.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `$url = 'http://www.mywebsite2.com/whitelist.php?email=' . $email; //<-- missing period`

Comment: Still nothing, I just noticed if I remove . $email and manually add in an email for testing purposes it doesn't work. Almost as if the link isn't being executed. Is there some flaw in how I'm doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that mywebsite2 had a bad password for the database connect that went unnoticed.